# Forum Bumping With MySQL Problems

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So, I have kinda got my forum bumping working... but there's one big noticeable problem:
It's bumping & showing it in 2 places...
Take a look:
http://www.seriouslycode.com/category?cid=1

You'll want to look at "test" - it's 1 topic, 2 places.

Here's my code:

```
    public function getTopics()
    {
        require("database.php");
        //$cat_id = strip_tags($cat_id);
        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `forum_topics` LEFT JOIN `forum_replies` ON `forum_topics`.`topic_id`=`forum_replies`.`topic_id` ORDER BY coalesce(`forum_replies`.`posted_on`, `forum_topics`.`posted`) DESC");
        if ($query->rowCount()==0)
        {
            return "<p>No topics, yet...</p>";
        }else{
            $returns = "<table class='table table-striped'>";
            $returns .= "<tr><th></th><th>Posted</th><th>Replies</th></tr>";
            while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                $returns .= "<tr><td><a href='topic?tid=".$row['topic_id']."'><h4>{$row['topic_title']}</h4></a><p>".substr($row['topic_body'], 0, 150)."...</p></td><td><h5>".User::getInformation($row['topic_starter'], "user_id", "username")."</h5><p>on {$row['posted']}</p></th><td><h4>N/A</h4></td></tr>";
            }
            $returns .= "</table>";
            return $returns;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Presumably there's more than one reply for that topic, which is causing it to be listed twice.  As there are more and more replies, you'll have it listed even more times. Have you tried the distinct keyword: `SELECT DISTINCT forum_topics.id, ...other field names... FROM ...` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "forum bumping"?

Comment: Everytime a reply is made, it's pushed to the top.

Comment: @cale_b - how would I use that? :)

Comment: If you only want to show one line per topic, then you need to use `GROUP BY topic_id`.

Comment: You also need to find the most recent post for each topic. There are many SO questions where this is answered. (When I say many, I mean it:  it's probably asked several times a day).

Comment: `$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `forum_topics` LEFT JOIN `forum_replies` ON `forum_topics`.`topic_id`=`forum_replies`.`topic_id` GROUP BY `forum_topics`.`topic_id` ORDER BY coalesce(`forum_replies`.`posted_on`, `forum_topics`.`posted`) ASC");` this shows the topics, but replies don't make a difference... and neither does
        `$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `forum_topics` LEFT JOIN `forum_replies` ON `forum_topics`.`topic_id`=`forum_replies`.`topic_id` GROUP BY `forum_topics`.`topic_id` ORDER BY coalesce(`forum_replies`.`posted_on`, `forum_topics`.`posted`) DESC");`